# Regex to find longest text fragment where last letter of word matches first letter of next word

Tags: c#, regex, match

For example if I had a text like

```
first line of text
badger Royal lemon, night trail
light of. Random string of words
that don't match anymore.
```

My result would have to be lines of words where the last character of each word matches the first character of the next word, even if there are separators in between. In this case:

```
badger Royal lemon, night trail
light
```

What is the easiest way to do this if I want to use Regex?

Comment: What about trying anything! Also implementing this functionality with a bit more code (with loops) seems quite easy.

Comment: I agree with @varocarbas, this seems way easier to do with a loop instead of trying to adapt a regex.

Comment: regex ... a nightmare. Write by hand this in whatever language. I think it can be solved in O ( N ). RegEx is not good for searching for the "max" value ... RegEx is good for searching patterns, not maximals or minimals

Comment: Something like this `\b\w*(\w)\b(?=\W+\1)` might be a start. But you are going to run into all kinds of headaches dealing with casing and with punctuation.

Comment: @DeanTaylor - this seems incorrect - fiskar16 is asking for words which have a last letter which matches the first letter of the next word, I think. He wants to stop when this pattern ends. I had the same first impression as you however.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression that matches each of the sequences of words would be:

```
(?:\b\w+(\w)\b[\W]*(?=\1))*\1\w+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You'll need to adjust the `\W` part depending on your rules regarding allowing full-stops, semi-colons, commas, etc.

Note this also assumes single letter words break a sequence.

You could then loop over the each of the occurrences and find the longest:

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?:\b\w+(\w)\b[\W+]*(?=\1))*\1\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length

        // @todo here test and keep the longest match.

        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

---

```
// (?:\b\w+(\w)\b[\W]*(?=\1))*\1\w+
// 
// Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Numbered capture
// 
// Match the regular expression below «(?:\b\w+(\w)\b[\W]*(?=\1))*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
//    Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) «\w+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w)»
//       Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) «\w»
//    Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
//    Match a single character that is NOT a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) «[\W]*»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\1)»
//       Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1 (case insensitive; fail if the group did not participate in the match so far) «\1»
// Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1 (case insensitive; fail if the group did not participate in the match so far) «\1»
// Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) «\w+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is NOT a regex implementation but ... maybe it helps. This is a simple implementation in C#:

```
public static string Process (string s)
    {
        var split = s.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (split.Length < 2)
            return null; // impossible to find something if the length is not at least two

        string currentString = null;
        string nextString = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < split.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var str = split[i];
            if (str.Length == 0) continue;

            var lastChar = str[str.Length - 1];

            var nextStr = split[i + 1];
            if (nextStr.Length == 0) continue;

            var nextChar = nextStr[0];
            if (lastChar == nextChar)
            {
                if (currentString == null)
                {
                    currentString = str;
                    nextString = nextStr.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (str.Length > currentString.Length)
                    {
                        currentString = str;
                        nextString = nextStr.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        return currentString == null ? null : currentString + "\n" + nextString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex won't really be able to tell the longest in the string.

But, using @DeanTaylor method if a global match you could store the longest 
based on the string length of the match.

This is a slight variation of his regex, but it works the same.

`(?:\w*(\w)\W+(?=\1))+\w+`

Formatted:

```
 (?:
      \w* 
      ( \w )          # (1)
      \W+ 
      (?= \1 )
 )+
 \w+
```